# ordering hours in an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of different times, and I need to order from low to high but directly from the driver, I'm dealing with the following:

```
  var arrayList =[{hora: '8:30'},{hora: '14:30'},{hora:'22:30'},{hora:'07:00'}] 

  $scope.array =$filter('orderBy')(arrayList, true);
```

the result is not as expected, that I'm wrong

Comment: This should work. `var sortedArr = arrayList.sort(function(a, b) { return parseInt(a.hora.replace(':'), 10) - parseInt(b.hora.replace(':', ''), 10)});`

Comment: You say that? http://plnkr.co/edit/y7imBQ7wIdkWbT97savb?p=preview

Comment: Check http://plnkr.co/edit/ne9AdMNuKSXIc2ZVQaMJ?p=preview

Comment: @tushar works great, maybe I could add to the response, and attach that function specifically made to do more to understand the result

Comment: @Tushar—there's no need for *parseInt*, the `-` operator coerces the values to Number anyway. And the array is sorted in place, so `arrayList.sort(function(a, b){return a.hora.replace(':','') - b.hora.replace(':','')});`. But these are comments, not answers…

Comment: @RobG Right! always forget about when to parse and when not to. And regarding comment, yes this should be comment as sorting questions has been asked thousand times. If you try to find, you'll get ~100 dupes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not proficient with angular, but usually, the problem sorting time variables is that they are stored as strings and not exactly referenced as time variables.

On this cases I usually split them in hours and minutes, multiply hours by 60 and add minutes, then sort for the resulting integer value.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.